# Can't insert spaces in code editors

Tags: editors, xubuntu

Since i recently installed CodeBlocks, I can't insert spaces in codeblocks, codelite or mysql-workbench editors.
When i press space the editor interprets it as a completion key unless there is no word to complete.
The only way to insert a blank space is to press "Supper+Space".
I tried to remove CodeBlocks and CodeLite but the problem persists in Mysql Workbench.
Configuration : 
uname -a :

```
Linux slxpc 3.2.0-57-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 21:35:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

cat /proc/version

```
Linux version 3.2.0-57-generic (buildd@toyol) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 21:35:10 UTC 2013
```

mysql-workbench --version

```
MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 6.0.8 11354  build 833
```

CodeBlocks version : 10.05

**FYI** : I don't have this problem in geany and leafpad.

Comment: This sounds like a simple key registration issue. First make sure your modifier keys are not "stuck" - restarting X should do that. Next check the keypress events in something like xev to make sure that space is actually registering a space.

Comment: @coteyr : I've already checked my modifier keys and none is stuck :-). i dont think i need to check key events once i don't have the problem in other editors or system windows. But anyway, xev returns a positive result :
    state 0x0, keycode 65 (keysym 0x20, space), same_screen YES

Comment: best to check the "is it plugged in" first, and I have seen the problem before.

Comment: Updating wxcrafter and codelite solves the problem in codelite only. But the problem remains in mysql-workbench and codeblocks.

Comment: @coteyr, be sure it's not a physical issue.

Answer (score 0):

After days of ties and failures I've just found the cause of my problem, and the solution (It may help someone else): 
I am using a non-US keyboard layout in my case it's a French one. In my Keyboard configuration :

```
MENU -> Parameters -> Keyboard -> Leyout
```

I set a "Franch(Variant)" leyout. I just changed it to "French" simply. And the problem disappeared everywhere !
I think CodeBlocks developers and Mysql-workbench ones have to think about this problem though !